# Maclaurin Series of $e^z/z^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

I think this was already asked but I couldn't find a question for a function with this kind of problem on the point where the Taylor series are developed around. I see on my text on complex variables (and on computation engines) that the Maclaurin series of the function $f(z) = e^z/z^2$ is written as

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2} + \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{z}{3!} + \frac{z^2}{4!} + \cdots$$

But since the first term of the series is $f(0)$ I don't know how they get these series for this function. I also see similar problem concerning the next terms for $f^{(n)}(0)$. Additionally, since the function is not analytic on zero I thought it could not have a Taylor series around it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That's a Laurent series, not a Taylor series. They just took the series for $e^z$ and divided everything by $z^2$.

Comment: @Javier What about $e^{1/z}$ and it's series $1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!z^n}$? Around zero the first term would be e^{1/0}

Comment: That's also not a Taylor series. A Laurent series is a generalization of a Taylor series that also works if the function has a singularity.

Comment: Okay, I can also get this replacing z by $1/z$ if $|z|>0$ on the series for $e^z$? But I think I can not assume that this resulting series is the Laurent series of $e^(1/z)$ around $z_0 = 0$...